# MSYS2 cannot delete file in Windows docker volume

Tags: windows, docker, msys2

I am experiencing an issue where MSYS2 running in docker can create and modify files in a mounted volume, but not delete them. This can be observed with commands where the deletion is explicit, such as `rm a.txt`, or with commands where the deletion is implicit, such as `sed -i 's/foo/bar/' b.txt` (b.txt should be edited in-place, and appears to be read, removed and recreated from the output (1)). The same files can be deleted with the equivalent DOS commands, such as `del a.txt`.

Using the following Dockerfile:

```
# Altered from https://github.com/StefanScherer/dockerfiles-windows/blob/main/msys2/Dockerfile
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:20H2

RUN powershell -Command \
    $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue' ; \
    Write-Output 'Downloading msys2' ; \
    curl.exe -o msys2.tar.xy http://repo.msys2.org/distrib/msys2-x86_64-latest.tar.xz ; \
    Install-Package -Scope CurrentUser -Force 7Zip4Powershell ; \
    Write-Output 'Extracting tar.xz' ; \
    Expand-7zip msys2.tar.xy . ; \
    Write-Output 'Extracting tar' ; \
    Expand-7zip msys2.tar C:/ ; \
    Write-Output 'Done'

RUN powershell -Command \
    setx /M PATH $('C:\msys64\mingw64\bin;C:\msys64\usr\bin;C:\msys64\mingw32\bin;' + $Env:PATH)
```

Build and launch the container with:

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:20H2
docker build -t docker-msys .
mkdir local
docker run -ti -v "$(pwd)/local:C:/local" docker-msys cmd.exe
```

Using MSYS2 commands from within the container, lets manipulate files with:

```
touch a.txt
cp a.txt b.txt
rm a.txt
rm -f b.txt
ls *.txt
```

If launched from a non-mounted directory, the following is observed:

```
C:\>touch a.txt
C:\>cp a.txt b.txt
C:\>rm a.txt
C:\>rm -f b.txt
C:\>ls *.txt
ls: cannot access '*.txt': No such file or directory
```

Both files have been deleted as expected.

If launched from a mounted directory, here `C:\local`, the following is observed:

```
cd C:\local
C:\local>touch a.txt
C:\local>cp a.txt b.txt
C:\local>rm a.txt
rm: cannot remove 'a.txt': Invalid argument
C:\local>rm -f b.txt
C:\local>ls *.txt
a.txt  b.txt
```

Both files still remain.

Other MSYS commands will have unexpected behavior in the mounted directory:

```
C:\local>sed -i 's/foo/bar/' b.txt
sed: cannot remove ./sed7E6QmG: Invalid argument
```

The files can be removed from the mounted directory with the equivalent dos command:

```
C:\local>del /Q *

C:\local>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 541F-A7C7

 Directory of C:\local

11/26/2020  04:05 PM    <DIR>          .
11/26/2020  04:05 PM    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  48,827,674,624 bytes free
```

Changing from a mounted directory to a named volume affect in nothing the situation. The previous output is the same when the container is launched with:

```
docker volume create local-volume
docker run -ti -v local-volum:C:/local docker-msys cmd
```

The problem doesn't appear related to my Dockerfile. I was able to reproduce it using a container from https://hub.docker.com/r/mizarjp/winci-msys2 .

```
docker pull mizarjp/winci-msys2:1909
docker run -ti --rm -v "$(pwd)/local:C:/local" mizarjp/winci-msys2:1909 cmd.exe
```

Once in the container, perform `set PATH=C:\msys64\mingw64\bin;C:\msys64\usr\bin;C:\msys64\mingw32\bin;%PATH%;` before repeating the previous tests to obtain the same results.

Finally, rather than installing MSYS2 inside docker, mounting it's directory inside a container produce the same situation.

Is there anything I am missing?

Details:

- Windows 10 Pro, 20H2, 19042.746
- Docker Desktop 3.1.0 (51484)
- MSYS2 (http://repo.msys2.org/distrib/msys2-x86_64-latest.tar.xz) 2020-07-03 19:34

(1) My humble interpretation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `--isolation=process` fixed it. `rm` no longer fails  for me!

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:20H2
docker build -t docker-msys .
mkdir local
docker run --rm -ti --isolation=process -v "$(pwd)/local:C:/local" docker-msys cmd.exe
```

Re-running the previous commands produces:

```
C:\>cd local
C:\local>touch a.txt
C:\local>cp a.txt b.txt
C:\local>rm a.txt
C:\local>rm -f b.txt
C:\local>ls *.txt
ls: cannot access '*.txt': No such file or directory
```